# Scala Expose a Case class nested in a trait

Tags: scala

I have a trait:

```
MyTrait {

  ...
  ...

  case class MyCaseClass(...)
}

object MyTrait {
  case class SomeOtherCaseClass(...)
}
```

For some of my tests, I would need to expose the MyCaseClass(...). How can I import this in my tests?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This probably doesn't do what you want it to do. Each instance will have its own type of MyCaseClass. in other words:

```
val a = new MyTrait {}
val b = new MyTrait {}
a.MyCaseClass.getClass != b.MyCaseClass.getClass
```

The general way to do this is either to put it top level:

```
case class MyCaseClass( ... )
trait MyTrait { ... }
```

Or if you want it more tightly scoped, put it in the companion object

```
object MyTrait {
  case class MyCaseClass(...)
}
trait MyTrait { ... }
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up doing what I did not want. My test class extends this trait that contains the case class in question!

Answer (score 0):

```
trait Mytrait{
  case class MyCaseClass(t:String)
}
object Mytrait extends Mytrait
```

then you can

```
import Mytrait._
```

and call `MyCaseClass("t")`

Comment: The original poster did not want to extend the trait!